# Unable to implement OTP with Web OTP API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, one-time-password

Web OTP API information provided by https://web.dev/web-otp is good. But demo provided in https://web-otp.glitch.me/ is working as of now with Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit).

The main reason I could see is that navigation credentials event for OTP is not getting triggered, and I don't understand why this is happening.

Is it problem with codebase of https://web-otp.glitch.me/ OR chrome mentioned version has any problem?

Steps to reproduce -

1. Open https://web-otp.glitch.me/ at your mobile browser.
2. As webpage says, get `@web-otp.glitch.me #12345` as text message to your mobile, from [unknown number](https://web.dev/web-otp/#no-dialog) . And you should receive a dialog message, asking you whether you want your browser to input this OTP.

Comment: The code provided in the links are correct, but you need some network carrier to send you SMS of OTP. Also, try using in a mobile browser(or change to a mobile device using the toggle in chrome).  And read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59150919/11926970

Comment: I checked the feature. I tried on mobike only, I sent myself code from contacts and unknown number. I am experienced developer, and I debugged the code too.      I am stating the event of navigator.credentials.get() for OTP is not getting trigged when an OTP is recieved. Can you check at your end and confirm me if issue exists at your end too? Because then I will report it to Chrome team

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you wrote and all the steps to reproduce the result?

Comment: Done https://stackoverflow.com/users/11926970/not-a-bot

Comment: anybody else wants to try?

Comment: @VaibhavArora It does not work for me as well. I get a popup to Allow to read the message but the navigator.credentials.get() never gets resolved, until it times out. Were you able to find out something?

Comment: nope, I couldn't found anything else
And didn't worked on it again

Comment: This is frustrating. I too am not able to get this to work, and I'm starting to wonder if this works for anybody.

Comment: Did anyone ever get this to work at all? The demo is not working for me either!

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the autofill permisson popup for all the messages. does anyone know how can i get this permission only for my domain messages

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the host name, incorrect host name may stop the Promise from getting resolved, i.e., `navigator.credentials.get`

Make sure your last line of text message should be like this:

`@<HOSTNAME_OF_WEBSITE> #<OTP>`

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting it only seemed to work if the last line with text before the last line (with the @ and #) ended in numbers.

Really weird.

So its like:

```
OTP code: <OTP>

Ignore this: 1111

@<HOSTNAME_OF_WEBSITE> #<OTP>
```

Answer (score 0):

The hostname must match the one where the input form lives. If the input form is on a subdomain then that must be your hostname. The @hostname must start on a new line followed by exactly 1 space, and "#" and then your code.

Everything before or after is ignored. So you should on the start of the message use a more user friendly code, in case the OTP auto fill fails, the user can still understand and type manually.

there is a chance to use a iframe with the input verification, check the WEB OTP documentation for that special case.